# iOS Sharing Extension : How to share both URL and Text together from Host app

Tags: ios, ios9, ios-extensions

I want to share both text and URL from host app using sharing extension.

```
- (BOOL)isContentValid {


for (NSExtensionItem *item in self.extensionContext.inputItems) {
    for (NSItemProvider *itemProvider in item.attachments) {
        if ([itemProvider hasItemConformingToTypeIdentifier:(NSString *)kUTTypeURL ]) {//
            [itemProvider loadItemForTypeIdentifier:(NSString *)kUTTypeURL options:nil completionHandler:^(NSURL *url, NSError *error) {
                if(url  ) {

                        self.linksURL= [url absoluteString];

                }
            }];
        }
        else if ([itemProvider hasItemConformingToTypeIdentifier:(NSString *)kUTTypeText ])
        {
            [itemProvider loadItemForTypeIdentifier:(NSString *)kUTTypeText options:nil completionHandler:^(NSURL *url, NSError *error) {
                if(url  ) {
                        self.linkTitleText= [url absoluteString];

                }
            }];


        }
    }

}





self.charactersRemaining=@85;
return YES;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Most of this is correct but the implementation of the method is wrong as you will return TRUE before anything has happened. Instead of doing it this way I suggest using a method with a completion handler like so...

```
-(void)contentURL:(NSExtensionItem *)extension completion:(void (^)(NSURL *url))completion {
    for (NSItemProvider *items in self.shareItem.attachments) {
        if ([items hasItemConformingToTypeIdentifier:(NSString *)kUTTypeURL]) {
            [items loadItemForTypeIdentifier:(NSString *)kUTTypeURL options:nil completionHandler:^(NSURL *url, NSError *error) {
                [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{
                    completion(url);

                }];

            }];

        }

    }

}
```

Then create a similar method for the text attribute.

**P.S Don't forget to put the operation in a block**